# INSERT query returns TRUE but does not work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to build an INSERT record query where the user can add new entries to the database using two drop down menus. The way this works is that, depending on who has logged in, $_SESSION variables take over and show the correct information in the drop down menus.

What I want it to do is, once a member of staff from a school has logged on, chosen the Subject Area and chosen the Year Group they want to manage, it shows two dynamic drop down menus with all the possible teachers that can teach that specific subject in the first menu, and a list of all the subject classes in that year in the second menu. The user can then select a teacher and a class and press the submit button to send the query off to the database for entry.

When prompted by the IF-command to test if the query worked, it recognizes the query as if it was TRUE, echos the SUCCESS line and redirects to previous page:

```
$result = $query_addteacher;
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query:'. mysql_error());
    }
    else
     { echo "Success!";
       header("location:addteachertest.php"); }
```

But the data hasn't actually been fed into the database at all. Below is the code for both the drop down menu's and the query:

```
 // Connect Command //
 mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) OR die("Can't connect");
 mysql_select_db($database_name) OR die("Can't connect to Database");

 $teacher = $_POST['teacher'];
 $class = $_POST['class'];

 // Query to insert data into the staffclass table //
 $query_addteacher = "SELECT @staff := idStaff FROM Staff WHERE Staff = '$teacher', @class := idClass 
 FROM Class WHERE Class = '$class';
 INSERT INTO Staffclass (idStaff, idClass)
 VALUES ($teacher, $class)";
```

```
 Teacher:
 <select name="teacher" id="teacher" form="addteacher" title="Teacher">
 <?php do { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row_teacherlist['Staff']?>"><?php echo $row_teacherlist['Staff']?>  
   </option>
 <?php
   } while ($row_teacherlist = mysql_fetch_array($teacherlist));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($teacherlist);
  if($rows > 0)
   {
     mysql_data_seek($teacherlist, 0);
     $row_teacherlist = mysql_fetch_array($teacherlist);
   }
 ?>
  </select>

   Class:
   <select name="class" id="class" form="addteacher" title="Class">
   <?php do { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row_classlist['Class']?>"><?php echo $row_classlist['Class']?></option>
   <?php
    } while ($row_classlist = mysql_fetch_array($classlist));
      $rows = mysql_num_rows($classlist);
      if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($classlist, 0);
      $row_classlist = mysql_fetch_array($classlist);
    }
   ?>
  </select>
```

I have a gut feeling that there is something wrong with the way I want the query to operate, by using straightforward MySQL commands. It works in this format (albeit the variables for teacher and class are not variable) when I enter it manually into MySQL so I wonder what I am doing wrong via PHP. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: ... When do you actually *execute* the query?

Comment: Additionally - your query string contains two separate queries; that won't work if you're using mysql_query - that will let you run one query at a time. If you want to run multiple queries in one call, then you'll have to use mysqli_multi_query

Comment: I've managed to make it work by turning the two variable creations in the beginning of the query into two seperate queries prior to the INSERT INTO one and just call up their variables instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$query_addteacher = "SELECT @staff := idStaff FROM Staff WHERE Staff = '$teacher', @class := idClass 
 FROM Class WHERE Class = '$class';
 INSERT INTO Staffclass (idStaff, idClass)
 VALUES ($teacher, $class)";

there are two queries in this fragment.
try query them seprately

Comment: Did this and then called up on these query results in the INSERT INTO one, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $query_addteacher;
```

You have not run a query, $result will evaluate to true as it is a string that evaluates to true.

```
$result = mysql_query($query_addteacher); // maybe?
```

Also, stop with mysql_() funcs and use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just set the result to the query variable. The query has to be *executed* on the server.

Consider doing something like this:
$result = mysql_query($query_addteacher);